# What Db structure should I use with 2 the same comment tables for 2 different parent tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

This is a tough design question for a application I'm working on. I have 2 different items in my app that both will use comments. What but I can't decide how to design my database.

There are 2 possibilities here. The first is a different comment table for every table that needs comments (normalized way):

```
movies -> movie_comments
articles -> article_comments
```

The second way I was thinking of was the use of a generic comments table and then have a many 2 many relationship for the comment and movie|article relations. Eg

```
comments

comments_movies (movie_id, comment_id)
comments_articles (article_id, comment_id)
```

What is your opinion on that the best method would be and can you give a good reason so I can decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i personally opt for 2nd solution

```
comments

comments_movies (movie_id, comment_id)
comments_articles (article_id, comment_id)
```

it is much more simple to maintain only on table model for logical Comment model e.g. when You wan't to add some feature to comments You just do it once or when You wan't count comments for specific user is much more easier because there are in one table

of course someone else could write his advantages of keeping that in multiple tables but You asked for opinions so here is mine :)

Comment: I've gone with this solution. The reason is that even when the comments would be different they would still be comments. So if you split them you'll in trouble if you want to count the comments. I've seen some reads on MySQL anti-patterns but this way of doing in feels the most natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping them separate has the benefit of supporting change without impacting the comments for the other entity (movie vs articles).  Assuming there are differences in attributes for a comment against an article vs. a movie.  Otherwise...

I suppose there could be a need for displaying a comment with an article and a movie.  But the consolidation would also support if you want to provide comment functionality for other entities in the future.

The answer depends on what you need currently, and a best guess of what you want to do in the future.  More details help us to know what to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best" method, because it is a straight-forward Normalisation question: the proposal is either correctly Normalised or it is not.

Actually, the first option is **not** Normalised, the Normalisation is not complete.  You have identical repeating groups of columns in two tables which have not been identified and grouped into a single table.

The second option **is** Normalised.  You have identified that, and placed them in a single table.

- at the logical level then, you have a many-to-many relation (not a table) between Movie and Comment, and between Article and Comment. End of story at the logical level.
- at the physical level, where n::n relations are implemented as Associative tables, you have CommentMovie and CommentArticle.
- as the Db expands and grows, life is simple, because:

  - any new column that is 1::1 with Movie.PK is placed in Movie
  - any new column that is 1::1 with Article.PK is placed in Article
  - any new column that is 1::1 with Comment.PK is placed in Comment
  - any new column that is 1::1 with CommentArticle.PK (the relation; PK is as shown (ArticleId, CommentId) ) is placed in CommentArticle.  This (adding attributes to an n::n relation) will now cause the table to show up on the Logical model.
  - any new column that is 1::1 with CommentMovie.PK (the relation; PK is as shown (MovieId, CommentId) ) is placed in CommentMovie.  This (adding attributes to an n::n relation) will now cause the table to show up on the Logical model.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your second choice:

```
movies -> movie_comments -> comments
articles -> article_comments -> comments
```

One comments table, two pivot tables(many to many).

This will keep all the same data in one table and just loosely linking them.  If you can get away with joins I usually recommend that for things that don't need to scale because joining can be a performance hit and a nightmare in cases. But this would be best for your case.

Answer (score -1):

```
comment_table
-------------
comment_id (int)
object_id  (int) 
comment    (varchar(max)) 
type       (int)
--------------
```

object_id refers to object such as movie ,i articles and so on.

type **equals 1**: comment was done to movie , 
 type **equals 2**:  comment was done to article

You can design your tables like this.

Comment: You are missing the id of the entity on which the comment was made.

Comment: Simplest way to loose data integrity because You can't define and use foreign key advantages (object_id is referencing 2 or more tables at the same time)

Comment: -1 No FKs ?!? That's not a Rdb, they are therefore not "tables", merely unrelated files without referential integrity.